# Shortest method to pass arguments to argv pointer

Tags: c

I wrote three ways of passing arguments to a function that accepts argv argument.

- The first method of using string literals is the shortest and works fine, but gives me a deprecated warning as my test harness is cpp based:

```
error: conversion
      from string literal to 'char *' is deprecated
      [-Werror,-Wc++11-compat-deprecated-writable-strings]
```

- The method using malloc works, though it's a tad bit longer.
- The last method causes a seg fault. Can you help me figure out the mistake in the third method, where I create an array with predefined size and copy the contents? Why does it fail?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define TEST3

int console_tester(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("argv: %s\n", argv[0]);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{

#ifdef TEST1
    // works, shortest, but gives compilation warnings
    char *test_cmd[2] = {"hello1", "hello2"};
    int result = console_tester(2, (char**)test_cmd);
#endif

    // works, verbose
#ifdef TEST2
    char *test_cmd[2];
    test_cmd[0] = malloc(10);
    test_cmd[1] = malloc(10);
    memset(test_cmd[0], 0, 10);
    memset(test_cmd[0], 1, 10);
    memcpy(test_cmd[0], "hello1", sizeof("hello1"));
    memcpy(test_cmd[1], "hello2", sizeof("hello2"));
    int result = console_tester(2, (char**)test_cmd);
    free(test_cmd[0]);
    free(test_cmd[1]);
#endif

    // crash and burn
#ifdef TEST3
    char test_cmd[2][10];
    memset(&test_cmd[0], 0, 10);
    memset(&test_cmd[1], 0, 10);
    memcpy(&test_cmd[0], "hello1", sizeof("hello1"));
    memcpy(&test_cmd[1], "hello2", sizeof("hello2"));
    int result = console_tester(2, (char**)test_cmd);
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214970/discussion-on-question-by-rookie-shortest-method-to-pass-arguments-to-argv-point).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the third example you're doing an invalid conversion:

```
char test_cmd[2][10];
memset(&test_cmd[0], 0, 10);
memset(&test_cmd[1], 0, 10);
memcpy(&test_cmd[0], "hello1", sizeof("hello1"));
memcpy(&test_cmd[1], "hello2", sizeof("hello2"));

int result = console_tester(2, (char**)test_cmd);
```

This produces a compiler warning for me when I strip off the `(char**)` brute-force casting:

```
warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'char (*)[10]' to parameter of type 'char **' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
```

Which really should be an error. You can't switch those arbitrarily. You don't have the right kind of structure to pass in, so you *must* convert it to the correct structure first.

The other two examples both use `char**` properly so they're fine.

This is why turning on *all* warnings your compiler has to offer can help narrow down problems quickly. C, and by extension C++, really does not care if you're asking to do something invalid, it'll do it if told to do it, and then crash or act really strange because of it.